# shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation doesn't work properly

Tags: iphone, locking, orientation, mode, portrait

I want to lock orientation to Portrait if device is iPhone, and allow all orientations if the device is iPad.

I have this code, but it doesn't lock iPhone in Portrait mode:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) 
    {
        return NO;

    }
    else
    {
    if (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
        return YES;
    }
    return NO;

}
```

What is the problem?

Comment: yes, iOS 6, but it should support < iOS 6

Comment: the thing you wrote would work on < iOS 6. For iOS 6, check my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if you will navigate the view then force orientation will not work but if you will     present your view then it will work very well and it works for me. In my project all screens are in portrait mode only but only one screen is in landscape mode.   
- (IBAction)startButtonClicked:(id)sender {

CTFailure_RemedyGameViewController *remedyGameController = [[CTFailure_RemedyGameViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"CTFailure_RemedyGameViewController" bundle:nil];
[self presentModalViewController:remedyGameController animated:NO];
[remedyGameController release];
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight);
}

@end
```

Comment: This would lock all views in portrait, I need all orientations for all viewcontrollers except one that must be locked in Portrait

Answer (score 0):

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) 
    {
        return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);

    }
    else{
        return YES;
    }

}
```

Try this. Hope this helps.

Comment: Doesn't work, I think it doesn't get called at all, if I put just return NO; it still rotates